# Tengo ploblemas con las sintaxs para declarar un varible php, que viene de un archivo php

Tags: php, html

Lo que intento es que en un pinput meto mi varible que traigo de php, pero al momento de enviarla nuevamente a otro formulario, la pantalla sale en blanco,

```
<?php
      $rutimagen = $_GET['rutimagen'];
      ?> 
<form action="exam.php" method="GET">
                <br>
                <!-- RUTA IMAGEN ENVIADA A FORMULARIO  -->
                <div>
                   <input type="text"  id="rutaimg" name="rutaimg" value="<?php echo $rutimagen ?>"> /// en el value es donde esta mi error
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: *pero al momento de enviarla nuevamente a otro formulario, la pantalla sale en blanco*. ¿Y qué debería salir? Además, hoy día ya no se trabaja así, mezclando código cliente / servidor. Deberías usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para enviar datos al servidor sin tener que recargar la página.

Comment: Dale, si, concuerdo que ya no debe trabaja asi, es un pequeño, php y html, en lo que etoy pidiendo ayuda, es que cuando mando la url que esta en una variable y la quiero mandar por un input, los caracteres los cambia.
probe este atributo pero igual no funciona 
value="<?= htmlspecialchars($rutimagen); ?>"
mi salida la tengo en un
header('Content-Type: image/png');

Comment: De primeras, no compruebas que exista el índice rutimagen en el get, por lo que puede darte el problema de índice no definido. Luego, en el formulario se llama de otra manera rutaimg. Luego no tienes un botón subir para enviar el formulario... por otra parte, estoy de acuerdo con @A.cedano, esto es un enfoque bastante antiguo, y encontrarás muchas dificultades si sigues esa forma.

Comment: vamos, solo estoy pidiendo ayuda con la sinstxis corecta input value para guadra ahi mi variable 
No te puedo subir todo el codigo, Si bien lo sabes, deberias entenderlo.

Comment: Lo demas funciona, solo que al mandar el input con esa varible que contine mi ruta, no fucniona, no se s tenga que ver con los caracteres.

Comment: Igual, Gracias de nada

Comment: Para el `$_GET` tienes que usar lo que hayas puesto en la etiqueta `name` de los elementos. Además, debes verificar que ese valor está. Y te falta un `;` para terminar la línea del `echo` donde asignas el `value`. Intenta esto: `<?php $rutimagen = $_GET['rutaimg'] ?? NULL;  if ($rutaimagen) { ?> <form action="exam.php" method="GET"> <br> <div> <input type="text"  id="rutaimg" name="rutaimg" value="<?php echo $rutimagen; ?>"> </div> </form> <?php } else { echo "Form. no enviado"; }` Además, te falta un botón submit para enviar el formulario como te señala @Jakala.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Para el `$_GET` tienes que usar lo que hayas puesto en la etiqueta `name` de los elementos. Además, debes verificar que ese valor está.
2. Te falta un `;` para terminar la línea del `echo` donde asignas el `value`.
3. El `form` debe tener un botón submit, para poderlo enviar.

Intenta esto:

```
<?php
    $rutimagen = $_GET['rutaimg'] ?? NULL;
    if ($rutimagen) {
?> 
    <form action="exam.php" method="GET">
        <br>
        <!-- RUTA IMAGEN ENVIADA A FORMULARIO  -->
        <div>
            <input type="text"  id="rutaimg" name="rutaimg" value="<?php echo $rutimagen; ?>" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />

        </div>
    </form>
<?php
    } else {
        echo "Form. no enviado o datos vacíos";
    }
```

De todos modos, yo evitaría la mezcla de bloques PHP / HTML que crea un código ilegible, y usaría Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para comunicaciones entre cliente (formulario / HTML) y servidor (código que es enviado a PHP para ser procesado). Esas herramientas te permiten enviar datos, recibir respuestas y actualizar el contenido en el cliente sin tener que recargar la página y sin mezclar código del cliente con código de servidor, como ocurre en el `input` de tu formulario.

Comment: he visto que muchas veces dice que es mejor usar la API Fetch de Javascript o que hoy en día ya no se trabaja así, pero que pasa si no se quiere usar JS?? Se ha trabajado toda la vida enviando formularios hacia archivos procesadores PHP, estos hacen un proceso o retornan una respuesta y, si algo sale mal el formulario antes lleno puede ser modificado y así sucesivamente. Se que es lo más nuevo y mejor pero nadie ha dicho que esta deprecado seguir con la forma tradicional o que **ya no se trabaja así**.

Comment: @OCHOA lo dicen los hechos y todos los sitios web más o menos modernos. No es que no se siga usando formularios para enviar datos al servidor, eso sigue en pie, lo que ha cambiado ha sido la forma de procesar esos datos: en vez de recargar la página para que esos datos sean enviados y recibir una eventual respuesta del servidor, se usa Ajax o Fetch para poder enviar esos datos y recibir una respuesta y en base a ella actualizar lo que haga falta en la interfaz del cliente **sin recargar la página** como era obligatorio hacer antes...

Comment: ... y si me apuras, Ajax y Fetch en cierto sentido empiezan a ser mayorcitos en este mundo de la informática y hoy ya se habla de programación reactiva y cosas por el estilo. Por ejemplo, hace poco empecé a trabajar con Symfony y te quedas admirado de lo fácil que es enviar al servidor y procesar datos de un formulario y actualizar la interfaz gráfica con dos o tres líneas de código y sin programar nada en Javascript por tu parte. Dicho eso, no es que esté prohibido trabajar al estilo del siglo pasado, quien quiera seguir haciéndolo nadie se lo impedirá, pero hoy no se suele trabajar así.

Comment: Bien, tomo su punto, como siempre muy bueno. Al final, es lo mejor, pero debe recordar que (según creo) en las "instituciones" de donde sea, en la mayoría enseñan los métodos tradicionales y creo que decirle a un novato que ya no se trabaja así los puede confundir, es mas, hoy por hoy lo recomendable y como más se trabaja son los frameworks, pero si no les enseñan la base no sabrán que es lo que pasa tras esos FW. Yo soy de los que creen que enseñar la base (complicada) y luego los Frameworks es buena idea.

Comment: Pero vea la pregunta, el OP ni siquiera ha hecho las validaciones básicas, eso significa que esta aprendiendo, y si le decimos algo como que esto ya no se hace así, entonces ¿su maestro los ha engañado? Es fácil confundirse cuando uno es nuevo en algo. Yo solo digo que quizás, seria bueno **recomendar** lo mas nuevo,  porque que sucede si el profesor no quiere nada de JS? entonces nuestra respuesta aunque sea excelente no le ayuda en nada al OP y ojo que su respuesta sin JS es muy buena, solo lo digo para evitar estresar a los nuevos. Es solo mi opinión :-)

Comment: @OCHOA Entiendo lo que señala. Yo he aprendido a trabajar en PHP a lo bruto, sin frameworks ni nada y aprendí muchas cosas dando tropezones. Ahora cuando descubro herramientas como Symfony y veo mi código de hace un par de años por un lado me digo *por qué no descubrí Symfony antes* pero por otro lado me alegro de no haberlo conocido antes, porque tengo una idea muy amplia de cómo funcionan las cosas tras bastidores. Ahora bien, sinceramente hoy día yo no enseñaría a programar envío de datos mediante formularios ignorando a Ajax o a Fetch, es demasiado obsoleto y no tiene ninguna utilidad ...

Comment: ... Y creo que no aporta nada aprender a programar así, advierto que es mi opinión sin ánimo de despreciar ningún método de aprendizaje. Y es que lo único que un principiante necesita saber en ese punto es que un formulario para que se envíe necesita que la página se recargue para que esos datos pasen al servidor. Pues de esa recarga se ocupa Ajax o Fetch, y eso te facilita llevar / traer cosas entre cliente y servidor sin moverte de la página. O sea, empezar a enseñar desde Ajax o Fetch no impide en nada que un principiante sepa cómo funcionan las cosas tras bastidores.